# Multiple equal signs in function definitions in Scala?

Tags: scala

This is a particularly un-Googleable query, but what is being represented when a function is defined with multiple equal signs on a single line such as in the following:

`def x_=(x: Int): Unit = internal = x`

Comment: Not much really, the first equal is part of the method name, the second one opens the method body and the third assigns `x` to a variable named `internal`.

Comment: @EndeNeu That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line in isolation is the setter portion of the getter/setter pattern in scala classes. A full example might look like this:

```
class Foo {
  private var internal: Int = 0
  def x = internal
  def x_=(x: Int): Unit = internal = x
}
```

The `def x` is the getter for private variable `internal`, while `def x_(x: Int)` is the setter. The effect is that through the magic of syntactic sugar the `x` member can be used on the left hand side of an assignment and will then set `internal` to the right hand side like this:

```
val foo = new Foo()
foo.x = 15
println(foo.x) // 15
```

The `_=(x: Int)` invokes the syntactic sugar of assignment, but it could just as well be called directly like this:

```
val foo = new Foo()
foo.x_=(15)
println(foo.x) // 15
```

As you can see, the former call is really just the latter method call with the underscore and parentheses omitted from the signature.